# Problema al inyectar archivos CSS en un modulo Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

estoy personalizando una copia de la plantilla default de Prestashop 1.6.
Creé un modulo llamado "elpsocialmedia", el módulo corre bien solo hasta que tengo que inyectar los archivos CSS.
Estoy usando el código que se ve en todo los foros:

```
$this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path)."elpsocialmedia.css", "all");
```

En el hook respectivo, pero no funciona. Si agrego archivos CSS en otros módulos de Prestashop como por ejemplo *"BlockCart"* o si incluyo los *hooks* en el *FrontController*, también los inyecta correctamente.

El problema está cuando intento inyectar CSS en módulos personalizados.

Adjunto el código, gracias por la atención.

**Nota:** *Trato de inyectar archivos erróneamente pero tampoco me muestra errores.*

**modules/elpsocialmedia/elpsocialmedia.php**

```
class ElpSocialMedia extends Module
{

    public $lsocial = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->name = "elpsocialmedia";
        $this->tab = "front_office_features";
        $this->author = "Elephants Noirs";
        $this->version = "0.1";
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->boostrap = true;

        $this->ps_version_compliancy = array("min"=>"1.6");

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l("Social Media Elephants");
        $this->description = "Manage social media";

        $this->lsocial = array(
            'youtube' => array(
                'url'=> '#',
                'icon' => 'fa-youtube'
            ),
            'facebook' => array(
                'url'=> '#',
                'icon' => 'fa-facebook'
            ),
            'instagram' => array(
                'url'=> '#',
                'icon' => 'fa-instagram'
            ),
            'googleplus' => array(
                'url'=> '#',
                'icon' => 'fa-google-plus'
            ),
            'linkedin' => array(
                'url'=> '#',
                'icon' => 'fa-linkedin'
            )
        );


        Cache::clean("hook_module_list");
    }

    public function getContent(){
        return $this->display(__FILE__, "getContent.tpl");
    }

    public function install(){

        return (parent::install() 
               && $this->registerHook("displayNav")
               && $this->registerHook("displaySectionSlider"));

    }

    public function uninstall(){
        if( !parent::uninstall() )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public function hookDisplayNav(){

        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path)."elpsocialmedia.css", "all");


        $assign = array(
            'lsocial' => $this->lsocial,
            '_path'=> $this->_path
        );

        $this->context->smarty->assign( $assign );

        return $this->display(__FILE__, "elpsocialmedia-nav.tpl");
    }


    public function hookDisplaySectionSlider(){

        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path)."elpsocialmedia.css", "all");

        $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path)."views/js/sliderheader.js");
        /*$varsAssign = array(
                'images'=> $images,
                'urlcss'=> $this->_path."views/css/sliderheader.css"
            );

        $this->context->smarty->assign( $varsAssign );*/

        return $this->display(__FILE__, "elpsocialmedia-slider.tpl");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que según esa ruta el archivo debera estar ubicado en

```
modules\mimodulo\mimodulo.css
```

Siempre es mejor opcion anadir el archivo/s css en el hook

```
hookDisplayHeader
```

Comment: Gracias por responder man y si pero de igual manera no funciona. No detecta ningún archivo CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Elimina la última función y añade lo siguiente:

```
    public function hookDisplaySectionSlider()
    {
        $varsAssign = array(
            'images'=> $images,
            'urlcss'=> $this->_path."views/css/sliderheader.css"
        );

        $this->context->smarty->assign( $varsAssign );
        return $this->display(__FILE__, "elpsocialmedia-slider.tpl");

   }

    public function hookHeader()
    {
       $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path."elpsocialmedia.css", "all");
       $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path."views/js/sliderheader.js");
    }
```

Modifica también install():

```
    public function install(){
        return (parent::install() 
               && $this->registerHook("displayNav")
               && $this->registerHook("displaySectionSlider")
               && $this->registerHook("Header"));
    }
```

Con esto deberías tenerlo.
Ah!! Y no olvides reinstalar el modulo o registrar manualmente el hook header